# Running H2O Falcon 7B, powershell 7 says "no GPU detected"

Tags: powershell, gpu, conda, h2o.ai

TLDR; I'm trying to run h2ogpt locally, specifically with the [h2oai/h2ogpt-gm-oasst1-en-2048-falcon-7b-v3](https://huggingface.co/h2oai/h2ogpt-gm-oasst1-en-2048-falcon-7b-v3) model in a conda environment. For some reason my GPU can't be found.

Long version:

I've activated the env, installed requirements text and extra torch requirement but when I try to run this command, Powershell 7 says "no GPU detected":

```
python generate.py -base_model=h2oai/h2ogpt-gm-oasst1-en-2048-falcon-7b-v3 -score_model=None -prompt_type=human_bot -cli=True -load_8bit=True
```

It does continue to download/load the weights but the computer can't cope, makes screen output stutter etc. I would try load_4bit but definitely says "no GPU".

I have run nvidia-smi:

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 536.67                 Driver Version: 536.67       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070      WDDM  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P0              31W / 151W |   1900MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
```

I've just tried to [installed CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=11&target_type=exe_local) to make sure I wasn't being silly - had it installed already, all drivers up-to-date too.

I assume Powershell is fine and can "see" my GPU because it can run 'nvidia-smi' and bring back info. Double checking the github docs I meet hardware requirements.

Looking through the [github read me for h2ogpt](https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md) I found a setting "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" which seems to be under 'What ENVs can I pass to control h2oGPT?'. I believe this is for if there are multiple GPUs but may be mistaken.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What makes you think it's PowerShell that's telling you "no gpu detected" when you're running python...?

Comment: More detailed logs would help. Sounds like it's bitsandbytes that prints out that warning.
Did you follow instructions from here to install bitsandbytes for Windows? 
https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/blob/main/docs/README_WINDOWS.md which installs https://github.com/jllllll/bitsandbytes-windows-webui, which has more instructions you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in your env:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

If it show "False" then your torch probably has wrong version and this a reason of "No GPUs detected". Just check torch after install requirements.txt.

In my [case](https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/issues/693), torch from cache was 2.1.0 version, so for unknown reasons installed 2.1.0 instead 2.0.1.
I cleaned cache, reinstalled python and used [manual for GPU](https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/blob/main/docs/README_WINDOWS.md) step by step and It's finally work.
Hope it helps you, too.